# Problems in three dimension array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, calloc

I defined the three dimensional array like this, but I it can't read any string in it? Where is the problem? Thanks!

```
int stuTotal, courseTotal,i,k;//a dynamic array
printf("Input the total number of students that you would like to import:");
scanf("%d", &stuTotal);
printf("Input the total number of courses that you would like to import:");
scanf("%d", &courseTotal);

char ***data = (char***)calloc(stuTotal,sizeof(char));//data
for(i = 0;i < stuTotal;i++){
    data[i] = (char**)calloc(courseTotal,sizeof(char));
    for (k = 0;k < courseTotal;k++){
        data[i][k] = (char*)calloc(20,sizeof(char));
    }
}
strcpy(data[0][0],"hello");
```

data[0][0] is shown to be empty.

Comment: First, do you really need a 3D array?  Second, you're using `sizeof(char)` for all allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments to `sizeof` are incorrect when you allocate the outer arrays - instead of

```
char ***data = (char***)calloc(stuTotal,sizeof(char));
```

it needs to be

```
char ***data = (char***)calloc(stuTotal,sizeof(char **)); // you're allocating N elements of type `char **`.
```

You can greatly simplify that call as follows:

```
char ***data = calloc( stuTotal, sizeof *data ); // sizeof *data == sizeof (char **)
```

and similarly

```
data[i] = calloc( courseTotal, sizeof *data[i] ); // sizeof *data[i] == sizeof (char *)
```

You should not need to cast the result of `malloc` and `calloc` unless you're working in C++ (in which case you should be using `new` or, better yet, some kind of container type) or an *ancient* C implementation (pre-1989).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using sizeof(char**) for 3d "data" array as every element of this 3d array is char**.

```
int stuTotal, courseTotal,i,k;//a dynamic array
printf("Input the total number of students that you would like to import:");
scanf("%d", &stuTotal);
printf("Input the total number of courses that you would like to import:");
scanf("%d", &courseTotal);

char ***data = (char***)calloc(stuTotal,sizeof(char**));//data
for(i = 0;i < stuTotal;i++){
    data[i] = (char**)calloc(courseTotal,sizeof(char*));
    for (k = 0;k < courseTotal;k++){
        data[i][k] = (char*)calloc(20,sizeof(char));
    }
}
strcpy(data[0][0],"hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

You specified invalid sizes of allocated objects.

You have to write

```
char ***data = (char***)calloc(stuTotal,sizeof(char **));//data
                                               ^^^^^^^   
for(i = 0;i < stuTotal;i++){
    data[i] = (char**)calloc(courseTotal,sizeof(char *));
                                                ^^^^^^ 
    for (k = 0;k < courseTotal;k++){
        data[i][k] = (char*)calloc(20,sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

If your compiler supports variable length array then you can allocate the required array with calling `malloc` or `calloc` only once. For example

```
char ( *data )[courseTotal][20] = 
    malloc(  sizeof( char[stuTotal][courseTotal][20] ) );
```

or

```
char ( *data )[courseTotal][courceName] = 
    calloc(  1, sizeof( char[stuTotal][courseTotal][courceName] ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t stuTotal = 5, courseTotal = 10, courceName = 20;

    char ( *data )[courseTotal][courceName] = 
        calloc(  1, sizeof( char[stuTotal][courseTotal][courceName] ) );


    strcpy(data[0][0],"hello");

    puts( data[0][0] );

    free( data );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
hello
```

In this case to free all the allocated memory it is needed to call `free` only once.